# Updating database with php and mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to update the last login date in my database each time a user logs into the website. It currently updates the LastLogin with a null value?

Why does the below code not work?

```
$this->mysqli->query("Update adminusers SET LastLogin = DATE('yyyy-mm-dd') WHERE Username = 'admin'");
```

Thanks!

Comment: RTFM? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

Comment: @Rafael session value of the current date ? eh why ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the `DATE()` function properly. You should use `CURDATE()` for current date in yyyy-mm-dd format

```
$this->mysqli->query("UPDATE adminusers SET LastLogin = CURDATE() WHERE Username = 'admin'");
```

Comment: `DATE(NOW())` should be `CURDATE()`